# Unable to Debug Locally when Using AWS SAM CLI, CDK, and Lambda Layers

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, aws-cdk, aws-sam-cli, aws-lambda-layers

I am unable to find example or good documentation on how to debug functions locally when building Lambda functions using the SAM CLI, AWS CDK, and Lambda Layers.

When building an RestApi and simple Lambda function with the CDK and then attempting to debug locally with VSCode using a launch configuration like:

```
{
  "type": "aws-sam",
  "request": "direct-invoke",
  "name": "hello:app.handler (nodejs12.x)",
  "invokeTarget": {
    "target": "code",
    "projectRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/infrastructure/handlers/hello",
    "lambdaHandler": "app.handler"
  },
  "lambda": {
    "runtime": "nodejs12.x",
    "payload": {},
    "environmentVariables": {}
  }
}
```

the import statements referencing modules from any layer throw an error such as:

```
{"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module '/opt/nodejs/utils'"
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Clone this repo: https://github.com/swizzmagik/sam-lambda-layer-test
2. Run npm install
3. Run npm run build
4. Run npm run api
5. Observe that the hello function properly resolves the layer references and works
   fine when called using curl or postman
6. Open handlers/hello/app.ts
   and try to debug in VSCode by opening the hello.ts file and hitting
   F5 Notice that the debugger starts but is unable to import the
   module and fails on this line import { buildResponseHeaders,
   handleError } from "/opt/nodejs/utils";

Comment: I am running into this exact issue. Any luck?

Comment: This isn't a solution to the question, but in case anyone else comes here trying to find a way to use NPM packages in their Lambda (aside from those contained in Node or AWS), you can do so without Lambda Layers by bundling them in with your Lambda. For example, just use the `NodejsFunction` construct from `@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-nodejs` instead of the vanilla `Function` construct from `@aws-cdk/aws-lambda`. This allows you to simply import the module (instead of importing from /opt) and you can still run the code locally.